# Copying files from a dynamically created folder over a network using batch files?

Tags: shell, batch-file, tfs, msbuild

I am using TFS2013 and when a build is completed, a new sub-folder would be created inside the Drop Folder. How can we copy files from this folder to another subfolder inside this folder (which has to be created by us) using batch files?
I have to run this batch file as Post-Build script in TFS2013 Build Arguments.

Problem is we need to take care of network paths, as the drop folder is located in Dev server. 
The batch file which I created runs perfectly fine when run from the Dev server itself but gives file not found error when run after a build.

Here is the code:

```
@echo off
::Date - 6/16/2015  ;; 6:58PM
::Find the directory containing the latest build - latest created directory.
FOR /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir "\\HQVEBLD01\TestDrop\TSOLB\" /od /b') do set latest=%%x
if not exist "\\HQVEBLD01\TestDrop\TSOLB\%latest%\_PublishedWebsites" mkdir "\\HQVEBLD01\TestDrop\TSOLB\%latest%\_PublishedWebsites"
:: above line creates published websites folder if it doesn't already exist
if not exist "\\HQVEBLD01\TestDrop\TSOLB\%latest%\_PublishedWebsites\NotificationGenerator" mkdir "\\HQVEBLD01\TestDrop\TSOLB\%latest%\_PublishedWebsites\NotificationGenerator"
if not exist "\\HQVEBLD01\TestDrop\TSOLB\%latest%\_PublishedWebsites\Tasks" mkdir "\\HQVEBLD01\TestDrop\TSOLB\%latest%\_PublishedWebsites\Tasks"


::first copy common files. our first folder is scheduled tasks folder
::
xcopy.exe "\\HQVEBLD01\TestDrop\TSOLB\%latest%\A.dll" "\\HQVEBLD01\TestDrop\TSOLB\%latest%\_PublishedWebsites\Tasks\"
```

:( 
Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks :)

Comment: Please note `/ad` option in `dir /ad /od /b` command. I didn't accentuate it equally in my answer.

Comment: Why torture yourself with batch files? This would be trivially easy in PowerShell.

Comment: @DanielMann can you tell how the code would look like in powershell? I am not very good at it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
mkdir "\\HQVEBLD01\TestDrop\TSOLB\%latest%\_PublishedWebsites\Tasks*"
rem                             this * is an invalid character     ^
```

You need not test the created folder existence; just use

```
md "\\HQVEBLD01\TestDrop\TSOLB\%latest%\_PublishedWebsites\NotificationGenerator"  2>NUL
md "\\HQVEBLD01\TestDrop\TSOLB\%latest%\_PublishedWebsites\Tasks" 2>NUL
```

Try `pushd` if any used command does not support [UNC paths](http://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html):

```
@echo off

pushd "\\HQVEBLD01\TestDrop\TSOLB\"

::Date - 6/16/2015  ;; 6:58PM
::Find the directory containing the latest build - latest created directory.

FOR /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir /ad /od /b') do set "latest=%%x"
::                            ^
mkdir "%latest%\_PublishedWebsites" 2>nul
:: above line creates published websites folder if it doesn't already exist
mkdir "%latest%\_PublishedWebsites\NotificationGenerator" 2>nul
mkdir "%latest%\_PublishedWebsites\Tasks" 2>nul


::first copy common files. our first folder is scheduled tasks folder
::
xcopy.exe "%latest%\A.dll" "%latest%\_PublishedWebsites\Tasks\"

popd
```

> When a UNC path is specified, `PUSHD` will create a temporary drive
>   map and will then use that new drive.  The temporary drive letters are
>   allocated in reverse alphabetical order, so if `Z:` is free it will be
>   used first.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I tried but its not working :( also the * was mistakenly added by me while posting the question here. Its not there in my original batch file.

Comment: is there any way I could refer to the newly created folder in drop folder without using the %latest% variable? That variable when accessed from TFS build is causing error because its referring to some other location where no file is present. Thanks :)

Comment: Use [setlocal](http://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html) somewhere at the script top, or use simply another variable name, e.g. `_latest` (note leading underscore) or `mylatest` or `tselat`